# How to optimize the below SQL query

Tags: sql-server

How to optimize the below query.

```
ALTER FUNCTION  [dbo].[GetVostroAccountByAccountWithInstitution]  

(    
 @P_AccountWithInstitution varchar(150)
)  
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)  
AS   
    BEGIN               
            DECLARE  @VostroAccount VARCHAR(15)  

            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM VostroAccConfig WHERE SwiftCode=@P_AccountWithInstitution)
                BEGIN
                    SET @VostroAccount=(SELECT VostroAcc FROM VostroAccConfig WHERE SwiftCode=@P_AccountWithInstitution)
                END
            ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM VostroAccConfig WHERE SwiftCode8=@P_AccountWithInstitution)
                BEGIN
                    SET @VostroAccount=(SELECT VostroAcc FROM VostroAccConfig WHERE SwiftCode8=@P_AccountWithInstitution)
                END

            RETURN @VostroAccount
    END
```

Comment: Not using a Multi-line Scalar function would be a start. Good indexing would be a second.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to not use a scalar function. An inline table valued function will perform much better. For a table function to be inline it MUST be a single query. Fortunately you can do this with the function you posted.

```
create function [dbo].[GetVostroAccountByAccountWithInstitution]  
(    
    @P_AccountWithInstitution varchar(150)
) returns table as return
    select top 1 VostroAcc
    from VostroAccConfig
    where @P_AccountWithInstitution in (SwiftCode, SwiftCode8)
    order by SwiftCode
        , SwiftCode8
```

The next step in making the perform quickly is indexing. But with no knowledge of the table it is hard to make suggestions.